# How do you establish the column number that an apply function is working on to use that number to retrieve a variable indexed by that number

Tags: r, apply

I am converting my for-loops in R for a model that has multiple input datasets. In the for-loop I use the current loop value to retrieve values from other datasets. I am looking to replicate this using an apply function (over columns in a dataset) however I'm struggling to establish index of the apply function in order to retrieve the appropriate variables from other data

The apply function references the column by the variable in the function which is fine and I've tried to use both colname (after having named my various columns by number) but have not had any joy. Below is an example dataset and for loop with what I'd like to achieve (simplified somewhat). The length of the vectors and the number of columns in the tabular dataset will always be equal.

```
iteration<-1:3
df <- data.frame("column1" = 6:10, "column2" = 12:16, "column3" = 31:35)
variable1<-rnorm(3,mean = 25)
variable2<-rnorm(3, mean = 0.21)
outcome<-numeric()
for (i in iteration) {
  intermediate<-(mean(df[,i])*variable1[i])^variable2[i]
  outcome<-c(outcome,intermediate)
}
outcome
```

The expected results are outcome above...trying this in apply

What I imagine it to be is this:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) (mean(x)*variable1[colnumber(x)])^variable2[colnumber(x)]
```

or perhaps

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) (mean(x)*variable1[x])^variable2[x])
```

but these two obviously do not work.

Answer (score 0):

first time user so apologies for any etiquette issues but found the answer to my own problem using the purrr package, but maybe this helps someone else

```
pmap(list(df, variable1, variable2), function(df, variable1, variable2) (mean(df)*variable1)^variable2)
```